# Property Line from NuGet-package Chart.js 2.0.2 not available

Tags: javascript, charts

I want to use charts in my HTML-pages, which i make in a web project made with VS 2015.
So i installed the NuGet-package Chart.js:
[Description for installation of Chart.js](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chart.js/)

After the installation i see two new JS-scripts in the scripts-folder:
Charts.js and Charts.min.js

Next i tried to implement a line diagram/chart in my page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Display charts with Chart.js</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <h3>Example for display of chart data</h3>
            <canvas id="buyers" height="600" width="400"></canvas>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var buyerData = {
                    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            fillColor: "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
                            strokeColor: "#ACC26D",
                            pointColor: "#fff",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#9DB86D",
                            data: [203, 156, 99, 251, 305, 247]
                        }
                    ]
                }

                var buyers = document.getElementById("buyers").getContext("2d");
                new Chart(buyers).Line(buyerData);
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But each time i try to start the page, i get a message, that the property Line does not exist.
What's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, but i'm not absolutely sure about it.
If want to post other answers, You are invited.

I replaced the line

```
new Chart(buyers).Line(buyerData);
```

by

```
var myChart = new Chart(buyers, { type: 'line', data: buyerData });
```

Further i discovered another option:

```
var myChart = Chart.Line(buyers, { data: buyerData });
```